# Query taking too much time to execute

Tags: oracle

I have this query which takes around 11-12 hrs to execute:

```
SELECT  A.EVENT_DATE SENT_DATE
       ,A.TRANSACTION_CODE EVENT_CODE
       ,COUNT(a.transaction_id) COUNT 
FROM customer A
WHERE A.REQUEST_DATE >= (select max(RUNPERIODFROM_DATE) from auditeventbatch where auditevent_code = 'CDPE')
  AND A.TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'STC'
  AND NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT /*use_nl(a b)*/1 FROM EVENTS_V1 B
 WHERE B.TRANSACTIONID=a.transaction_id
  AND TRUNC(B.EVENT_DATE) = A.CCE_EVENT_DATE
  AND B.TRANSACTION_STATUS='STC'
)
GROUP BY A.CCE_EVENT_DATE
        ,A.TRANSACTION_CODE
```

Is there any way I can rewrite this to reduce the execution time of this.The view CDS_EVENTS_V1 has millions of record it it.I don't have the option the make the view as materialized view.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one of the problems is this row:

```
  AND TRUNC(B.CCE_EVENT_DATE) = A.CCE_EVENT_DATE
```

`TRUNC` makes the optimizer to ignore the index(if exists , if not - add it) . I suggest adding another column containing the trunced value and comparing by that column.

Also, if not exists, add the following index:

```
CDS_EVENTS_V1 (transactionid,CCE_EVENT_DATE,TRANSACTION_STATUS)
cds_auditeventbatch (RUNPERIODFROM_DATE,auditevent_code )
```

Comment: @peter Thanks for the quick reply. DS_EVENTS_V1 is a view and can't add index to a view.

Comment: Are the columns calculated in the view? If not you can add it on the tables of the view @NishaSharma

Comment: you could add a functional index for TRUNC(CCE_EVENT_DATE) rather than adding another column

Comment: @peter Columns are not getting calculated in the view.And the table already has index for transactionid and TRANSACTION_STATUS.Only for CCE_EVENT_DATE we don't have index in the table.

Comment: Yes, you can listen up to davegreen100 , add the index on `transactionid,transaction_status,trunc(cce_event_date)` , that should help @NishaSharma